# Delete a exisitng component from a managed (Release) package

Tags: managed-package

We have a package called XYZ for an app we are planning to publish on the AppExchange. The version 1.2  had a field called  'Level__c'

The version 1.2 of the package successfully went through Security Review. We are presently at version  1.8. The app is ready to be made public on AppExchange.

We need to delete the field Level__c from the package as it is creating issues in the functionality.

Is this possible? We can not make a new package on a new org, as the security review was done on this org.

Comment: Hi Lex, thanks for the reply!
Is it possible to delete the package and then again create a new one with useful components?

Comment: Posted an answer in reply to your comment

Comment: How many people (other than you) have installed the package?

Comment: No other user have installed the package, as we were on testing phase we haven't made it public for other users.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you cannot delete a package that has been uploaded, and you can only create one managed package per org. So, no, I'm afraid you can't. The only option is to migrate all your stuff to a new org and create a new package from there.

But, as you say, you're already on the AppExchange with your current package, that means you'd have to re-enter the security review. People that already installed your current application will not be able to update to the new version, but they will just have to install the new version and remove the old one, so you have to come up with some way of migrating the data from the old version to the new one.

Comment: Would you think salesforce technical support help us in this regard?
I'm not sure it is worthy or not but i would try to raised a case.

Comment: I don't expect them to be able to help you. I've created cases in the past to request removal of a packaged (and already released and installed) field but they could not help me. But if you are actually considering to create a new org and a new package, they may be inclined to make a new security review easier, faster or maybe cheaper.